# Will blackberry 10 support Qt application 

Tags: qt, blackberry-10

Can nokia QT apps be ported to blackberry 10? If so what are the pros and cons ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BB OS 10 will support Qt. You can find useful information on BB [GitHub](http://blackberry.github.com/)